# Faraday::ConnectionFailed error in Azure Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kubernetes, devise

I am getting error for azure login.After getting authentication call,I am getting below error.Currently my application running in Docker which is working fine.Now I have moved code to kubernetes and now I am getting this error.

```
Faraday::ConnectionFailed
execution expired
Extracted source (around line #178):
            
    else
      Socksify::debug_notice "Connecting directly to #{host}:#{port}"
      initialize_tcp host, port, local_host, local_port
      Socksify::debug_debug "Connected to #{host}:#{port}"
    end
  end

Rails.root: /DEVICEAPP

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
socksify (1.7.1) lib/socksify.rb:178:in `initialize'
socksify (1.7.1) lib/socksify.rb:178:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:937:in `open'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:937:in `block in connect'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/timeout.rb:103:in `timeout'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:935:in `connect'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:920:in `do_start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:909:in `start'
faraday-net_http (1.0.1) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:146:in `request_via_request_method'
faraday-net_http (1.0.1) lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:131:in `request_with_wrapped_block'
```

Comment: Could you please make [your issue reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) by editing and adding information about how did you deploy you application in Kubernetes - `yaml` definition files, steps you followed? Where are you getting exactly this error?

Comment: I got the issue.There is no network connectivity in inside pod hence I am getting error.

Comment: Do you have idea about enabling network inside pod?

Comment: Make sure you have [CNI plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/) installed. If possible, please add information that I asked in previous question - `yaml` definition files (if you can), steps you followed to create the pod. The logs in the question are from `kubectl logs <your-pod`?